# nhibernate "multi key" mapping - bank accounts/adress data for different entities

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, data-modeling

I am searching for the right way to model the following situation with nhibernate:

**bank account** and/or **address data** cloud be linked to the following entities

- Customer
- Contract
- Claim
  *...

which are totally different, so that it cloud not linked to common parent.

At the moment, my only solution is the use of unique link tables for every constellation:

- bank_to_customer
- bank_to_contract
- ...
- add_to_customer
- add_to_contract

and

bank has mapped collections like

- customers
- contracts
- ...

address has equal collections like

- customers
- contracts
- ...

I have a bad feeling to solve the requirement to search for a bank account or street and show which entities are linked with the result set.

Maybe four results for "abc street" in adresse query than it is necessary to query all "add_" link tables four times to identify all links...

perhaps there is a better solution or modeling of the problem?

thank for any suggestion

Comment: is customer/Contract to address/bankaccount one-to-many or many-to-many?

Comment: many-to-many (maybe the bankaccounts could be reduced to one-to-many)

Answer (score 0):

maybe any / many-to-any Mapping adresse the problem

http://jzo001.wordpress.com/2013/01/21/nhibernate-many-to-any-mapping-composite-identifier-unidirectional-relationship/

but it is coupled with inheritance

Answer (score 0):

use many-to-any with an interface

```
interface IHaveContacts
{
    ICollection<Contact> Contacts { get; }
}

class Contact
{
    ICollection<IHaveContacts> EntitiesWithContacts { get; private set; }
}
```

unfortunatly it is not supported with FNH as it seems. use hbm.xml for this mapping alone or edit the mapping before adding it to the config.